# PrintDocument default DPI value in C#?

Tags: c#, dpi, printdocument

I created some graphics to be printed assuming that the `PrintDocument` class uses the standard 96 dpi (an inch of the drawing requires 96 pixels on the printout), but when I print those graphics on paper they appear smaller thus not having the appropiate dimensions.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

So what is the default DPI value of the PrintDocument class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your PrintPage event handler, the e.Graphics.PageUnit property is set to GraphicsUnit.Display.  Which makes 100 "pixels" equal to one inch on paper.  Regardless of the printer DPI.  Close to the default DPI for the screen, not quite.

Comment: @HansPassant 100 pixels instead of 96 solved my problem. Thanks so much Hans! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351487/printdocument-default-dpi-value-in-c#comment45047331_28351487):

> In your `PrintPage` event handler, the `e.Graphics.PageUnit` property
>   is set to `GraphicsUnit.Display`. Which makes 100 "pixels" equal to
>   one inch on paper. Regardless of the printer DPI. Close to the default
>   DPI for the screen, not quite.